# Find normal vector of a parametric vector function given $r'(t_0)$ and $r''(t_0)$

Tags: calculus, vectors

The full question I was asked  was to find the following, but If i have help finding the normal vector $N(t_0)$, I think I can proceed normally.

Find the following:

- Tangent Vector: $T(t_0)$
- Normal Vector: $N(t_0)$
- Binormal Vector: $B(t_0)$
- Curvature: $k(t_0)$

given

- $r'(t_0) = <-6, 4, 12>$
- $r''(t_0) = <4, 2, 6>$

I started by finding the magnitudes of r' and r''  their cross product (for curvature) giving me

- $||r'(t_0)|| = \sqrt{36 + 16 + 144} = 14$
- $||r''(t_0)|| = \sqrt{16+4+36}= 2\sqrt{14}$
- $||r'(t_0) crossr''(t_0)|| = ||<0, 84, -28>|| = 28\sqrt{10}$

Thus as $T(t_0) = \frac{r'(t)}{||r'(t)||}, T(t_0) = \frac{1}{14}r'(t) = \frac{1}{14}<-6,4,12>$

The part where I get stuck is finding $N(t_0)$ as $N(t_0) = \frac{T'(t)}{||T'(t)||}$, I figure $T'(t) = \frac{1}{14}r''(t)$, thus $||T'(t)|| = \sqrt{(\frac{2}{7})^2+(\frac{1}{7})^2+(\frac{6}{7})^2} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{7}}$, so finally $N(t_0) = \frac{1}{14}\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}<4,2,6>$, however the book I'm using states that the answer is $\frac{\sqrt{10}}{70}<20, 3, 9>$ I have no clue how to reach that point, and some better insight would be appreciated.

I'm truly awful at math, so I apologize if this is due to some minor error I made and forgot to check on.